# Ansible iteration over an array with data

Tags: arrays, ansible

```
-name: SFTP | inbox
file: path="{{ item.home }}/{{ item.username }}{{ item.suffix1 }}/{{ item.inbox }}" mode=0775 owner="{{ item.username }}" group="{{ web_user }}" state=directory
with_items: "{{ clients }}"
when: suffix1 is defined
 
-name: SFTP | outbox 
file: path="{{ item.home }}/{{ item.username }}{{ item.suffix1 }}/{{ item.outbox }}" mode=0775 owner="{{ item.username }}" group="{{ web_user }}" state=directory 
with_items: "{{ clients }}" 
when: suffix1 is defined
 
TASK [sftp-user : SFTP | inbox **************************** 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test1', u'home': u'/home/test1', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox'}) 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test2', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox', u'home': u'/home/test2', u'suffix2': u'_right', u'suffix1': u'_left'}) 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test3', u'home': u'/home/test3', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox'})
 
TASK [sftp-user : SFTP | outbox **************************** 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test2', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox', u'home': u'/home/test2', u'suffix2': u'_right', u'suffix1': u'_left'}) 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test1', u'home': u'/home/test1', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox'}) 
skipping: [server1] => (item={u'username': u'test3', u'home': u'/home/test3', u'inbox': u'Inbox', u'outbox': u'Outbox'})
 
clients:
 - username: test1 
   home: /home/test1 
   outbox: Outbox 
   inbox: Inbox
 
 - username: test2 
   home: /home/test2 
   outbox: Outbox 
   inbox: Inbox 
   suffix1: _left 
   suffix2: _right
 
 - username: test3 
   home: /home/test3 
   outbox: Outbox 
   inbox: Inbox
```

There is an array with clients, some clients have a suffix for a folder, some do not. Example: all clients have suffixes - folders are created if the first client does not have a suffix, and the second has suffix - folders creation is skipped. Skipped the first client and create the second client. How to solve this problem,since all clients in this code are skipped, please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*item.suffix1* has to be tested. The condition is evaluated on each iteration

```yaml
when: item.suffix1 is defined
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent 2 days working on this problem :)